# Google Calendar reminder emails

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

Working on a project for a small medical practice. Is there a "path of least resistance" to auto-emailing patients of their appointments as set in Google Calendar if they haven't agreed to receive them?

The practice has a policy for confirming appointments 2-3 days prior to the appointment date as there have been many cancellations in the past, so this would normally be done manually. I'm trying to determine the quickest resolution to automating this workflow via some Google Apps setting, WordPress plugin, API or otherwise. Is there an industry standard for this?

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar unfortunately doesn't allow to send reminders to guests. You might want to check out [Cal2SMS](http://www.cal2sms.com/) and this [list](http://moresiteslike.org/sites-like/appointment-link.com).

Comment: Also see http://youcanbook.me